# Scala list folding

Tags: scala

I'm trying to learn scala. It's hard.

I currently have a tree in the form

```
class Node(children:List[Node], value:Int){

}
```

I want to calculate a total cost defined by value + the sum of the totalcost of the children. My java background made me do this:

```
def totalCost() {
  var total = value
  for (child <- children){
    total = total+child.totalCost
  }
  return total
}
```

now I know I should be folding or reducing, but it's not coming out. Could some of you frendly helpers give me a hand here?

Comment: I don't quite understand how this question is not within scope. @Michael K: Could you review your closure, and if it is in fact out of scope, explain how, so I won't be asking out of scope questions on this site again?

Comment: I would second that. The question was to review the given `totalCost` method, which works fine, but isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: Probably it should be in stack overflow, it should be moved instead of getting closed.

Comment: I apologize; this was flagged as OT and I didn't read the post closely enough. This does have working code and is on topic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already a `sum` function:

```
def totalCost = value + children.map(_.totalCost).sum
```

Answer (score 2):

A left-fold is an elegant solution too:

```
class Node (children:List[Node], value:Int) {
  def totalCost : Int = (value /: children) (_ + _.totalCost)
}
```

Comment: Just a note for recent readers: `/:` is not used any more (it might even be deprecated, though I am not sure - see https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9607). People write `foldLeft` instead.